# Spark-submit how to set the user.name

Tags: hadoop, apache-spark, hadoop2

want to set

```
mapreduce.job.user.name=myuser
```

Tried

```
spark-submit  --class com.MyClass
--conf mapreduce.job.user.name=myuser \ 
--conf spark.mapreduce.job.user.name=myuser \
--master yarn  \
--deploy-mode cluster \
```

Also tried

```
--conf user.name
```

in environment of Spark UI
showing

```
user.name yarn
```

Comment: Did you try the old trick of `export HADOOP_USER_NAME=wtf`?

Answer (score 1):

In Spark 3, set SPARK_USER as a system property.

https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/util/Utils.scala

```
  /**
   * Returns the current user name. This is the currently logged in user, unless that's been
   * overridden by the `SPARK_USER` environment variable.
   */
  def getCurrentUserName(): String = {
    Option(System.getenv("SPARK_USER"))
      .getOrElse(UserGroupInformation.getCurrentUser().getShortUserName())
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Set as [Runtime-Environment Variable](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/configuration.html#runtime-environment)

try:

```
--conf spark.executorEnv.mapreduce.job.user.name=myuser
```

---

> `spark.executorEnv.[EnvironmentVariableName]` -   Add the environment
>   variable specified by EnvironmentVariableName to the Executor process.
>   The user can specify multiple of these to set multiple environment
>   variables.

Comment: Huh - `mapreduce.job.user.name` is a Hadoop property, not a Linux environment variable. Plus, the YARN job user is set by the Spark driver when connecting to the YARN Resource manager to allocate the job and its containers; when the executors start running in the containers, the job is already defined...